# How to make the manufacturer attribute applicable to configurable product in Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

I would like the manufacturer attribute to apply to configurable products as well, not only simple products. Because right now in my module calling getAttributeText("manufacturer") returns nothing for configurable products because the manufacturer is set on the simple product level and cannot be set on the configurable product level.

Is it possible to set this somehow?

Comment: I hope someone can suggest something about how to solve this problem. The manufacturer attribute is built in Magento 2, but even if I add a brand new attribute I don't know how to make it applicable to configurable products. So a more generic answer would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the column `catalog_eav_attribute`.`apply_to` value from 'simple' to null or add additional entity types like below:

Apply the manufacturer fitler to all types:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET apply_to =NULL  WHERE attribute_id=<attributed_id>; -- 83 in my case
```

Apply the manufacturer filter to simple and configurable types:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET apply_to ='simple,configurable'  WHERE attribute_id=<attributed_id>; -- 83 in my case
```

**NOTE**: To make sure changes are represented in Magento 2 admin, as well, you need to reindex: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` from your website root.

Comment: For all those reading, this is the case probably for the whole Magento 2. I can confirm it's still the case in Magento 2.2.5, and the fix applies. NOTE: You need to reindexer:reindex so that the changes made manually are shown in the admin.