# Manufacturer attribute applicable to configurable product at Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, manufacturer

Unfortunately, I have the same problem:

[How to make the manufacturer attribute applicable to configurable product in Magento 2.2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213510/how-to-make-the-manufacturer-attribute-applicable-to-configurable-product-in-mag/242477#242477)

The changes at 'apply_to' and the reindex had no success to me :-(

The attribute `manufacturer` at the backend has the id 83 in the url....

`https://www.***.de/shop/admin_***/catalog/product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/83/key/*****/`

but with:
`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'manufacturer'`

i get an `attribute_id` = 81

Magento Ver.-2.2.5

Anyone else has a idea?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the column catalog_eav_attribute.apply_to value from 'simple' to null or add additional entity types like below:

Apply the manufacturer fitler to all types:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET apply_to =NULL  WHERE attribute_id=<attributed_id>;
```

Apply the manufacturer filter to simple and configurable types:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET apply_to ='simple,configurable'  WHERE attribute_id=<attributed_id>;
```

To make sure changes are represented in Magento 2 admin, as well, you need to reindex: php bin/magento indexer:reindex from your website root

Comment: many thanks for your response. of course I tried everything - without success!

Today I did the update to 2.2.6 and now it works!

Comment: Great, sounds good

Answer (score 0):

My reputation isn't high enough to comment, but I would like to add to the previous correct answer that the full "apply_to" if you want to be able to have a manufacturer on every product type would be:

```
simple,virtual,downloadable,bundle,configurable
```

Thanks for the great advice!